# How to compile multiple files in ROOT

Tags: c++, compilation, root-framework

I wrote a C++ program (with a `main.cpp`, and various header and implementation files) that compiles fine under g++. Now I am trying to compile it in Cern's ROOT library, but I do not know how to, since the only way I know how to compile files in ROOT is by using `.L main.cpp`.

How can I include multiple files in ROOT?

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear what you mean by 'ROOT'. Root directory? The ROOT library (http://root.cern.ch)? Something else? The 'root' tag seems to refer to all kinds of things.

Comment: @bames53 yeah I meant the cern ROOT library. Thanks!

Comment: What compiler on what platform you are using?

Comment: A quick search for "cern root library" yields: http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/users-guide

Comment: @j_kubik I'm using ROOT, which appears to be an interpreter for C++? I installed it on both OS X and Ubuntu

Comment: @jeffamaphone thank you! but I got that too, and I don't readily see anything to help me run a program with several different files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most reliable way to use ROOT (at least historically and currently) is to ignore the interpreter other than for the simplest explorations and explicitly compile your C++ programs against the ROOT libraries. For example, use

```
g++ MySource.cc `root-config --libs --cflags` -o foo
```

to compile an executable "foo" from a single source file. For more info on that helper script run "root-config --help".

Multi-file programs/libraries are nothing special provided that you supply the required args to point at the ROOT libraries and headers (and that the libs are available in LD_LIBRARY_PATH at runtime.) Standard C++ guides will explain that step if needed. You can safely put this into a makefile, too.

For my money this is both easier and more reliable than using the .L etc. commands in the CINT interpreter. Last time I tried, ACLiC was actually compiling against a temporary (and mangled) version of the specified source file, so any error messages from the compiler were pretty much useless!

Comment: By the way, is the backtick supposed to be before `-o foo`? It doesn't seem to be able to find the ROOT header files otherwise, but now I get the error message `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPhysics`. Any ideas what might be causing this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oops, yes, the backtick should be before the -o: that last flag and arg are options for the compiler. Fixed now!

Comment: Re. not being able to find -lPhysics... I have had some trouble with this, even though the command line looks ok. Try looking on the filesystem in the ROOT library install area for libPhysics.so (argh, such generic names! cf. libCore, libGraphics... sigh) and if it's in an unusual place, force that with a -L/path/to/dir. I'm not sure, but the ordering of the args from root-config might be a bit dysfunctional: try just "root-config --libs --cflags" to see the command. Hope that helps.

Comment: Aha, thank you! I finally got it to compile a `foo` file by copying the `root-config` output and removing `-lPhysics`. But actually running `./foo` crashes, even though it works just fine in ROOT itself with .L. Something to do with vectors, probably unrelated to ROOT. Weird. I could have sworn the same segment of code had worked fine on another project. But oh well, I think I'm about to give up on getting ROOT to "just work." Thanks for all the help Andy!

Answer (score 3):

I use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org) to compile my ROOT-based projects. 
If you have a project directory  proj/ and it contains src/ and bin/, you'll need 3 CMakeList.txt files, one in each directory.

A simple example CMakeList.txt in the main project directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project (SOME_PROJ_NAME)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(bin)
```

src/ directory is where you keep your .h and .cxx proj. library files. Example CMakeList.txt file:

```
# get all the *.cxx filenames, to compile them into a lib
file(GLOB SOME_PROJ_LIB_SRCS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cxx")
# include ROOT library and include files
include_directories(/path/to/root/dir/include/dir)
link_directories(/path/to/root/dir/lib/dir)
# and compile src into a library
add_library(Proj_lib_name ${SOME_PROJ_LIB_SRCS})
# here, list the ROOT libraries you require
target_link_libraries(Proj_lib_name dl Core Cint RIO Net Hist Graf Graf3d Gpad Tree Rint Postscript Matrix Physics MathCore Thread Gui pthread m)
```

bin/ directory is where you keep your app .cxx files and it has a CMakeList.txt file:

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
include_directories(/path/to/root/dir/include/dir)
link_directories(/path/to/root/dir/lib/dir)
add_executable(example_app.exe example_app.cxx)
target_link_libraries(example_app.exe Proj_lib_name dl Core Cint RIO Net Hist Graf Graf3d Gpad Tree Rint Postscript Matrix Physics MathCore Thread Gui pthread m)
```

Finally, to compile ROOT-based code with CMake, out of source, you create a "build" dir in your top level project dir, so that your dir structure looks like this:

```
proj/
  bin/
  build/
  src/
```

Then

```
cd build
cmake ..
```

Your binaries will be located in build/bin/ directory

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I would simply `.L <filename>` for each file I want, since `.L` tells ROOT to "load the contents of file in memory." Though now I am not too sure which order to load the files in, as they are giving me errors.